# From second-order differential equation and constraints, prove $y(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove :
Let $P : R → R$ be a continuous function such that $P(x) > 0$ for all $x ∈ R$. Let $y$ be a twice
differentiable function on R satisfying $y''(x) + P(x)y'(x) − y(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ R$. Suppose
that there exist two real numbers $a, b$ $(a < b)$ such that $y(a) = y(b) = 0$. Then $y(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ [a, b]$.

What I've gotten so far is, $p(x) = y(x)-y''(x)/y'(x)>0$, so, $|y(x)| > |y''(x)|$
or, $y''(x)$ is negative...

Comment: that is how life is, my dear friend

Comment: Welcome to MSE, the title hits hard.. one word- resilience

Comment: Sorry, but even with compassion and understanding, a title talking about personal psychology has no place here.  It is unrelated to the true nature of the request.  Imagine everyone had such titles!  What a mess!

Comment: Life without humor sneaking in ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume there exists some point $x \in (a,b)$ such that $y(x) > 0\,$ ($y(x) < 0$). This implies there is a maximum (minimum) at some $c \in (a,b)$ where $y'(c) = 0$ and $y''(c) < 0\,$ ($y''(c) > 0$). In either case substituting into $y''(c) + P(c) y'(c) - y(c) = 0$ leads to a contradiction.